# How to get week number from a date in php?

Tags: php, date

I have a question to ask, please help me to find the solution:

I have a start date as 6 aug 2014. And i have assigned week numbers(week 1 and week 2) only for each week starting from the date 6 aug 2014 as below:

6 aug 2014 - 9 aug 2014 : week1
10 aug - 16 aug 2014: week2
17 aug 2014 - 23 aug 2014 : week 1

and so on...

Now i want to find the week(whether week1 or week 2 ) for any date greater than start date lets eg 1 oct 2014

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "W" parameter in date function to get iso week of the year and use mod operator to get week 1 or week 2

```
$myweek = ((date("W") - date("w", $start_date)) % 2) + 1;
```

Comment: but my start date can be changed everytime. so the week value for any date should be calculated on the basis of start date only

Comment: thnks but it is giving me a notice Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered